# How to implement download function by taphold? [using phonegap]

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have lots of thumbnail and they are in the same class. I want to make a    function to let user download each photo by taphold. How can I implement the function after I press yes in alert box?

```
  $(document).on( 'taphold', '.swipebox',tapholdHandler());
  function tapholdHandler( event ){
    navigator.notification.alert(
      "Do you want to download this photo?",
      "Download",
      "No",
      "Yes",
      {
        onClose: function(buttonIndex) {
          if (buttonIndex == 1)
           download(); 
       }
     }
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the notification.alert incorrectly, try like this:

```
$(document).on( 'taphold', '.swipebox',tapholdHandler);

function tapholdHandler( event ){
    navigator.notification.alert(
        "Do you want to download this photo?",
        alertCallback,
        "Download",
        ["No","Yes"]);

}

function alertCallback(buttonIndex){
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
       download(); 
}
```